# Set include directory for linker (ld) on OSX

Tags: macos, linker, include-path

I have a problem with linking a compiled program (see [github repo](https://github.com/rkrug/squeezelite-R2) for details).

The osx specific makefile section is here:

```
CFLAGS  = -v -arch x86_64  -Wall -fPIC -O2 -I./include $(OPTS)
LDFLAGS = -v -arch x86_64  -lpthread /usr/local/lib/libportaudio.a -framework CoreAudio -framework AudioToolbox -framework AudioUnit -framework Carbon

EXECUTABLE ?= squeezelite-osx

include Makefile
```

The compilation works fine, but during the linking it fails with:

```
Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.2.0
Thread model: posix
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -dynamic -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.11.0 -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk -o squeezelite-osx main.o slimproto.o buffer.o stream.o utils.o output.o output_alsa.o output_pa.o output_stdout.o output_pack.o decode.o flac.o pcm.o mad.o vorbis.o faad.o mpg.o dsd.o dop.o dsd2pcm/dsd2pcm.o process.o resample.o -lpthread /usr/local/lib/libportaudio.a -framework CoreAudio -framework AudioToolbox -framework AudioUnit -framework Carbon -lFLAC -lmad -lvorbisfile -lfaad -lmpg123 -lsoxr -lSystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/7.0.2/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a
ld: library not found for -lFLAC
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [squeezelite-osx] Error 1
```

The library which is not found is in the folder `/usr/local/include` and I think I have to add this path to the include path of the linker.

How can I add the path `/usr/local/include` to the include path of the linker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linker doesn't use include files; that's the compiler (actually the pre-processor, but let's keep it simple).

Instead you need to tell the linker that it should look in `/usr/local/lib` using the `-L` option:

```
-L/usr/local/lib
```

Note: you can provide more than one `-L` option to the linker.

Comment: Thanks - that worked nicely. Is there something similar I could use for the ```/usr/local/lib/libportaudio.a``` file to avoid specifying the path there?

Comment: @Rainer Once you've specified it, it applies to all libraries (i.e. provides an additional place to look for them).  It should find that file if you add the `-lportaudio` option.

Comment: OK - replaced ```/usr/local/lib/libportaudio.a``` with ```-lportaudio``` and it compiles. Thanks a lot.